# Magento 2 How can I hide the price and total from cart and checkout summary?

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, jquery, totals

I want to hide price and totals from cart/checkout Summary. You can see in below image.

[image]

How can I achieve this functionality with a custom module? Is there any common file from I can hide the price?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Utsav,
you can see the html files on this location: vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/cart/totals

Comment: yes, I can see that, but i need the common file/function which called each time when total, subtotal, grand total called.

Comment: There is no such file where you can hide the price and it will affect for all areas. You need to edit every files which uses prices to display for different areas.

Comment: Thanks all. but let you know which files need to be change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overriding the js file called "price-utils.js" from

```
**Vendor\Magento\module-catalog\view\base\web\js\price-utils.js**
```

into the module with "requirejsconfig.js" in our module as below:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils': 'Name_Module/js/price-utils'
        }
    }
};
```

then copy the file into your module

```
@ app\code\Name\Module\view\frontend\web\js\price-utils.js
```

now change return value in **"function formatPrice"** it is return formated price.

That's it. 
one thing I point here for everyone it will hide the price from cart totals, checkout totals, summery and **from product option's price as well.**

As I required to hide price from front end it is a good solution for me.

Hope it will help others.

Happy Coding.....

Answer (score 2):

You can try below layout XML to remove such JS components.

Assume your custom module name is "**Company_MyModule**".

**step 1)** To Remove elements from **Cart Page**

create **checkout_cart_index.xml**

under

***/app/code/Company/MyModule/view/frontend/layout***

File : **checkout_cart_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="checkout_cart_item_renderers"/>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.shipping">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="block-summary" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                            </item>

                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.totals">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">                        
                            <item name="block-totals" xsi:type="array">                            
                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                </item>
                            </item>                        
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>    
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**step 3)** To Remove elemnt from **Checkout Page**

create **checkout_index_index.xml**

under

***/app/code/Company/MyModule/view/frontend/layout***

File : **checkout_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">          
          <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="totals" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">                                                       
                                                        <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                        <item name="shipping" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                        <item name="grand-total" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**step 2)** Remove static content and cache

```
sudo rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*
sudo rm -rf var/pub/static/*
sudo rm -rf var/cache/*
sudo rm -rf var/generated
sudo rm -rf var/composer_home
sudo rm -rf var/page_cache
sudo rm -rf var/view_preprocessed
sudo rm -rf pub/static/frontend/*
```

You can check this [link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/howdoi/checkout/checkout_customize.html) for more information.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Appreciated your answer. That is correct. but I don't want to hide the whole block. just need to hide the prices.
Thanks

Comment: You can check my 2nd answer to hide specific component only. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To Hide prices blocks only,  use below XML to hide "**subtotal**","**grand-total**","**tax**",**"Shipping"** components.

File: **checkout_cart_index.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="checkout_cart_item_renderers"/>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.totals">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">                        
                            <item name="block-totals" xsi:type="array">  
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">  
                                <!-- Disable subtotal-->
                                <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="array">                            
                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>    
                                <!-- Disable shipping-->
                                <item name="shipping" xsi:type="array">                            
                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>  
                                <item name="tax" xsi:type="array">                            
                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>   
                                <!-- Disable grand-total-->
                                <item name="grand-total" xsi:type="array">                            
                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>    
                                </item>
                            </item>                        
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>    
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```